Sharing audio between UTM and MacOS like coherence mode in Parallels
I am on a Macbook air and I have Skullcandy PLYR PRO headsets which require SkullCandy HQ(EQ software) which is only available for windows 10 and above therefore I can't run that on Mac.I have a UTM VM windows 11 arm and there the EQ software works fine but I was wondering if I can "extract" the audio from the mac and feed it to the EQ software and then onto the headsets just like Parallels coherence mode.
